# What container to use when I need to know both the max value and who has achieved it?

Tags: c++, arrays, maps

I'm trying to work through the beginner exercises from a website.

"Requires:
variables, data types, and numerical operators
basic input/output
logic (if statements, switch statements)
loops (for, while, do-while)
arrays

Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of pancakes eaten for breakfast by 10 different people (Person 1, Person 2, ..., Person 10)
Once the data has been entered the program must analyze the data and output which person ate the most pancakes for breakfast."

I'm unsure on how to get the program to call out the person which enters the most number of pancakes eaten? Surely this would need to be done with a key and value, but the requirements state 'arrays' but not 'maps'?

Below is the code I have come up with, but this only outputs the maximum number of pancakes eaten, so not really answering the question!

Thanks so much for any help!

*** I've only used 5 people to quicken the process before I know exactly how to do it ***

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "how many pancakes did you eat for breakfast?" << endl;

    int person1, person2, person3, person4, person5;
    cout << "Person 1: ";
    cin >> person1;

    cout << "Person 2: ";
    cin >> person2;

    cout << "Person 3: ";
    cin >> person3;

    cout << "Person 4: ";
    cin >> person4;

    cout << "Person 5: ";
    cin >> person5;

    int array[5] = {person1, person2, person3, person4, person5};
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > temp)
        {
        temp = array[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "The most pancakes eaten was " << temp << "by " <<  endl;

}
```

Comment: An array should work fine...

Comment: You can make a struct that holds both the name and the number of pancakes eaten.

Comment: Mats is right, array is fine, also you can skip the creation of five separate variables. Instead you can create an int array of five elements and then use a loop for the input.

Comment: Using `Map ` for this question will be an overkill which seems unnecessary.

Comment: Using any container, even an array, is overkill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Surely this would need to be done with a key and value

This is not the only way of doing it. Another way is to use an indexed collection with no key, and make an assumption that position `k` corresponds to a key `k` that can be computed from a position alone. For example, if you have an array of ten items corresponding to ten people numbered 1 through 10, then the data for a person number `k` could be stored in the array at position `k-1`. No keys are required in this situation.

This long explanation means that if you store the best `i` in addition to best `tmp`, you'll have your answer after the loop:

```
int temp = 0;
int res = -1;
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    if (array[i] > temp) {
        temp = array[i];
        res = i;
    }
}
cout << "The most pancakes eaten was " << temp << "by " <<  (res+1) << endl;
```

Note the `res+1` is printed, not `res`. This is because arrays are zero-based, while counting is one-based.

This could be further shortened using a common idiom of using the initial element as the current best, and starting your iterations from `1`:

```
int res = 0;
for (int i = 1 ; i<5 ; i++) {
    if (array[i] > array[res]) {
        res = i;
    }
}
cout << "The most pancakes eaten was " << array[res] << "by " <<  (res+1) << endl;
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much! I was struggling with how to assign each person a value for the program to call. The use of 'res' has worked great.

Comment: And that can be even simplified with standard library and `std::max_element`

Answer (score 1):

What if you kept track of the maximum amount of pancakes eaten as you took input?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// To execute C++, please define "int main()"

int main() {
  int numPeople = 5;

  int maxPancakes = -1;
  int maxPerson = -1;

  int currentPancakes = -1; 

  for (int i = 1; i < numPeople; i++) {
    cout << "Person " << i << ": ";
    cin >> currentPancakes;

    if (currentPancakes > max) {
      max = currentPancakes;
      maxPerson = i;
    }
  }

  cout << "Person " << maxPerson << " ate the most pancakes: " << maxPancakes;

  return 0;
}
```

*Note: my c++ is pretty rusty, I haven't tested this solution. Just an idea ;)*

Comment: If you are not using an array, why start at `0` when "Person" starts at `1`?

Comment: That's fair! I initially thought of a solution using an array and then dumped it for something a little more simple :) Edited the solution

Comment: you can look at my solution for other improvement  ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Map for this question will be an overkill. Array is more than enough. You don't even need to iterate through the array to check who ate the most. The operation for getting the max is actually **O(0)** because we can update who ate the most as you are entering the values.

```
int main(){
    const int NUM_PEOPLE = 10;
    int cakesEaten[10] = {0}; 
    int maxEaten = 0;
    int personId = 0;

    cout << "How many pancakes eaten by:" << endl;
    for(int x=0; x<NUM_PEOPLE; x++){
        cout << "person " << (x+1) << ":";
        cin >> cakesEaten[x];

        if (cakesEaten[x] > maxEaten){
            maxEaten = cakesEaten[x];
            personId = x;
        }
    }
    cout << "The most pancakes was eaten by person " << personID << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your `O(0)` is wrong, you do the `n` tests to find the max. It could take `O(1)` memory as optimization, but even your solution takes `O(n)` memory.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need **any** storage at all.

As the numbers are entered, compare them and store who has the current max, and its value

Starting with fake values is not needed if you use the first person's value as the start value, this way negative values, could be included if entered.  That may be nonsensical here, but in general, its a better practice.

Also note if we want `people` to start at `1`, then it makes more sense to start it at `1`, then start at `0` and try to remember to always add `1`.

This is also very easy to expand to more people, just change `total_people`

```
int main() {
  const int total_people=5;

  cout << "how many pancakes did you eat for breakfast?" << endl;

  int what;
  cout << "Person 1: ";
  cin >> what;

  int who=1;
  int max_value=what;

  for (int person = 2; person <= total_people; ++person) { 
    cout << "Person " << person << ": ";
    cin >> what;
    if (what > max_value) {
      max_value=what;
      who=i;
    }
  }
  cout << "The most pancakes eaten was " << max_value << "by " << who << endl;
}
```